# Error in Accessing SMTP setting from App.config

Tags: c#, email, smtp, app-config, configuration-files

Hello I am trying pull smtp setting section same as we do for appsetting by using `ConfigurationManager.appsettings`.but I am getting an error while doing it for SMTP section using:

```
Configuration oConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var mailSettings = oConfig.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;
```

The error is

> Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>       Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Configuration.Configuration [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Configuration.dll]'
>   to 'System.Configuration.Configuration [E:\Spring 2018\Information
>   Processing
>   Techniques\K142164_GR2_IPT_Assignment2\Rough\email\email\System\Configuration\Configuration.cs(19)]'  email   E:\Spring
>   2018\Information Processing
>   Techniques\K142164_GR2_IPT_Assignment2\Rough\email\email\Mail.cs

Comment: is your machine has v4.5.1 .Net Framework?

Comment: Hello I got the solution thanks anyway.